# How to get back to main menu after executing a function in switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

This is my code. I just want to ask how can I go back to the inputting what switch statement that I want to perform or my main menu after executing a function in the switch statement. It seems that goto function is not working here in java.

```
public class FINAL 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner option = new Scanner (System.in);
        int ch;
        {
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ WELCOME ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("[1] - New");
        System.out.println("[2] - Open");
        System.out.println("[3] - Save");
        System.out.println("[4] - Save As");
        System.out.println("[5] - Item Record");
        System.out.println("[6] - Exit");
        System.out.println("Choose what option do you want to perform.......");
        ch = option.nextInt();
        
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                New();
                break;
        
            case 2:
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("GFdfdf");
                break;
        }
        }  
    }
```

I am creating a file in this function and after executing it in case 1, I want to go back to my main menu to choose what case in the switch that to perform

```
    static void New()
    {
        Scanner name = new Scanner  (System.in);
                String filename;
                
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
                filename = name.nextLine();
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");
                
                try 
                {
                    File myfile = new File(filename);
                    if (myfile.createNewFile())
                    {
                        System.out.println("File Created " + myfile.getName());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("File already exist.");
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("An Error Occured");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best way to do this, but a simple straightforward solution would be to simply run a while loop around the code in your main function. In order to avoid an infinite loop, I added `case 3` which changes `running` to `false` - exiting the loop.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean running = true;
        Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ WELCOME ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("[1] - New");
            System.out.println("[2] - Open");
            System.out.println("[3] - Save");
            System.out.println("[4] - Save As");
            System.out.println("[5] - Item Record");
            System.out.println("[6] - Exit");
            System.out.println("Choose what option do you want to perform.......");
            int ch;
            ch = option.nextInt();

            switch (ch) {
                case 1:
                    New();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("GFdfdf");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    running = false;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

You can do the same thing with yet another inner loop around the switch case if you don't want to return to the main menu.

However, this solution can quickly become a problem as you add different sections of code. The solution would be to break this code into functions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really helpful :D

Comment: You're welcome. You can pick it as an answer if you find it sufficient :)

Comment: Tip: You can Move this line `Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);` outside of the while loop, we only need to create it once.

Comment: How about if I have a nested switch? How can I go back to my main menu now?

Comment: Then you need to use `break;` to exit the nested switch, and the outer switch, or you need to use a boolean flag to get back to the `while` loop that prints the main menu. Otherwise, you can put the main menu in a different method and call that method whenever you want the menu printed.